Error in nodejs and npm while writing files
This error is halting my progress since last week... I've tried AI, Google search, Github, asking experienced people, nothing works.
So I'm just a starter in react and nodejs. I was following Dr. Angela Yu's Udemy course for Web dev and now I'm at a standstill. When I downloaded and installed nodejs everything was normal. I chose everything default except I chose npm package manager in custom installation.It seems npm is unable to write and is also unable to create a package.json file. Node version: 22.11.0 and Windows 11 Home.
This is what I got when trying to create a *react app:  npx create-react-app*
node:fs:2344
return binding.writeFileUtf8(
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file path...\package.json'
at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2344:20)at createApp (C:\Users\divyo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:271:6)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {errno: -4058,code: 'ENOENT',syscall: 'open',path: 'C:\Users...\package.json'}
Even a simple *npm init* is not working.
npm error code ENOENTnpm error syscall opennpm error path C:\Users...\package.jsonnpm error errno -4058npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users...\package.json'npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.npm error enoent
How can it find package.json if it does not even create it. I once tried even manipulating npm permissions to allow write but wasn't allowed to do that. I tried repairing through nodejs installer setup but to no avail.

Could you please put the whole error in a single place? Don't split the message into multiple pieces. It's unreadable that way.
